# JSON issues in Linux, but not in iOS

Tags: python, json, urllib2, google-finance, stockquotes

I am trying to get stock information for a particular ticker, and having issues with implementing the code in Linux Ubuntu in a virtual environment. I am getting the error below:

*ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded*

What's strange is I am not getting the same error when I am running the same code in the iOS terminal. Please see my code below for more details.

```
import json, urllib2

link_base = "http://www.google.com/finance?&q="
link_tick = "MU"
link_read = urllib2.urlopen(link_base+link_tick).read()
link_data = json.loads(link_read[3:])
link_info = link_data[0]

price = float(link_info["el"])

print price
```

Could someone explain to me why this is happening, and what I can change in my code to fix the issue in Linux Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you use the same version of Python and all relevant modules?

Comment: I have 2.7.13 in iOS and 2.7.12 in Linux.

Comment: Your `link_read` is an HTML document, not JSON, so the Linux behavior is correct.

Comment: The URL you're looking for is: https://www.google.com/finance/info?&q=  Please update your code and try again, please note I've tried this and the field el does not exist, but print link_data and you should see the full output of the response. Thanks @DYZ for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks DYZ and Aaron Fahey!